# CarouselView Not Updating After Adding Item to Itemssource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I am attempting to implement a Carousel View in Xamarin.Forms where the user can add items to the carousel by pressing a button. I can initially load some items, but when I try to add another item at run time, the change is not reflected in the app. During debugging, I can confirm that the ObservableCollection that Itemssource is bound to does have an item added to it, but the UI does not reflect that added item.

Here is my ConfigurationView.xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:JoyHost_GUI.Views;assembly=JoyHost_GUI"
             x:Class="JoyHost_GUI.Views.ConfigurationView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding ConfigName}" />
                <Button Text="+ Add Channel" Command="{Binding AddChannelCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}"
                          IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                          Loop="False"
                          VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                          x:Name="ChannelsCarousel">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:ChannelView BindingContext="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" />
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            </CarouselView>
            <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="Blue"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
namespace JoyHost_GUI.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ConfigurationView : ContentView
    {
        ConfigurationViewModel configurationViewModel;

        public ConfigurationView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            configurationViewModel = new ConfigurationViewModel();

            BindingContext = configurationViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
namespace JoyHost_GUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ConfigurationViewModel : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ChannelModel> Channels { get; }
        public ICommand AddChannelCommand { get; }
        private string _configName;

        public ConfigurationViewModel()
        {
            Channels = new ObservableCollection<ChannelModel>();
            AddChannelCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                Channels.Add(new ChannelModel());
            });
        }

        public string ConfigName
        {
            get => _configName;
            set
            {
                _configName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void AddChannels(IEnumerable channels)
        {
            foreach(ChannelModel channel in channels)
            {
                Channels.Add(channel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In short, after the AddChannelCommand is executed, the underlying Channels structure is updated, but not the GUI of the app.

Comment: you are adding empty `ChannelModels` - does that contain any data that would be visible in the Carousel?  You may also need to be sure that you are updating on the UI thread - use Essentials MainThread to do this

Comment: Yes, the ChannelModels have default values when they're initialized, and even if they didn't I would see some entries and whatnot. I also have an IndicatorView that does not show any update. I just tried changing the AddChannelCommand to run
`MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Channels.Add(new ChannelModel()); });`
but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. As a test, I would comment out everything in ChannelView, and add a single label with hardcoded text `<Label Text="test"/>`. See if it succeeds in adding a trivial view. If it does, then add to question source code for `ChannelView`.

Comment: Did you   implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That's a good idea, unfortunately even when the ChannelView is reduced to just a label I still get the same behavior. @Adrain Zhu -MSFT I had it implemented earlier but got rid of it while trying to fix things. I just added it back in so that `OnPropertyChanged();` is called whenever the Channels member is set and also whenever the channels.CollectionChanged event is fired. Still the same behavior, though.

Comment: Is this on ios, android, or uwp?

Comment: I had been testing just on UWP, but since you asked I tried with android. Interestingly enough, everything works just fine on android, so it seems to be a UWP-specific issue.

Comment: You could run the sample code on UWP to see if it works https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/CarouselViewDemos/CarouselViewDemos